# Links to mobile.twitter URL's don't Onebox in chat

Tags: bug, chat, twitter

URL links to tweets embed nicely in a nice chat onebox that provides the text of the tweet. It's awesome. But when the URL is for twitters mobile site, such as https://mobile.twitter.com/RagnarTornquist/status/232911044018843648 the onebox doesn't work.

Can we fix this please? Thanks!

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, if all the OneBox function did was chop "mobile." off the URL, it'd work and reach the main site tweet, which is what works now. But the data can probably be grabbed either way.